# Facebook image upload from mobile website

Tags: ios, facebook

Does anyone know how the facebook mobile website allows users to upload images from a mobile file system? Looks like Twitter is doing it as well.

Answer (score 0):

iOS6 supports standard `<input type="file">` fields.